# Using subqueries in Eloquent/Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Here's the query in raw SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT `characters`.`id`,`characters`.`refreshToken`,
           `characters`.`name`,max(`balances`.`created_at`) as `refreshDate`
        FROM `characters`
        INNER JOIN `balances` ON `characters`.`id` = `balances`.`character`
        WHERE `characters`.`refreshToken` IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY `characters`.`id`
) AS `t1`
WHERE `refreshDate` < '2017-03-29';
```

I've tested this in phpMyAdmin and it returns the expected results.  However I'm using the Eloquent and Laravel libraries in my PHP app and I'm not sure how to approach this.  How exactly do subqueries work in this case?

Comment: Give it a try before asking how to do something, sorry Peter but SO isn't coding request website! You can find in Laravel's docs a lot of things about this.

Comment: I have and have drawn a blank.  If you read the question I asked how subqueries work, I didn't ask for someone to give me the solution.  Looking to learn here not just be given code.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, i was looking solution of this issue in Lumen. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do a subquery as a table but need to create the subquery first and then merge the bindings into the parent query:

```
$sub = Character::select('id', 'refreshToken', 'name')
    ->selectSub('MAX(`balances`.`created_at`)', 'refreshDate')
    ->join('balances', 'characters.id', '=', 'balances.character')
    ->whereNotNull('characters.refreshToken')
    ->groupBy('characters.id');

DB::table(DB::raw("($sub->toSql()) as t1"))
    ->mergeBindings($sub)
    ->where('refreshDate', '<', '2017-03-29')
    ->get();
```

If that is your entire query you can do it without the subquery and use `having()` instead like:

```
Character::select('id', 'refreshToken', 'name')
    ->selectSub('MAX(`balances`.`created_at`)', 'refreshDate')
    ->join('balances', 'characters.id', '=', 'balances.character')
    ->whereNotNull('characters.refreshToken')        
    ->groupBy('characters.id')
    ->having('refreshDate', '<', '2017-03-29');
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use subqueries in Eloquent by specifying them as a closure to the `where` method. For example:

```
$characters = Character::where(function ($query) {
    // subqueries goes here
    $query->where(...
          ...
          ->groupBy('id');
})
->where('refreshDate', '<', '2017-03-29')
->get();
```

You have to chain your methods to the `$query` variable that is passed to the closure in the above example.

If you want to pass any variable to the subquery you need the `use` keyword as:

```
$characterName = 'Gandalf';

$characters = Character::where(function ($query) use ($characterName) {
    // subqueries goes here
    $query->where('name', $characterName)
          ...
          ->groupBy('id');
})
->where('refreshDate', '<', '2017-03-29')
->get();
```

Comment: thanks for this - do subqueries have to go inside a where clause or can I also use them in a from clause?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about that. You could try and see if that works.